# I can't remember what I was doing last night

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, story

I can't remember what I was doing last night... Could you help me figure out what I was doing?

This is what I can remember...

> I was standing in a room. Some guy from another country, Scandinavian I think, complained about a priest attacking his wife. He said his wife retaliated by threatening the priest and his master, which caused the man's wife's counterpart to protect the priest's master... He then said his wife attacked both of the church's priests, accidentally bumping into someone in the process. This is where it started getting really weird. He then said his wife's counterpart moved something about the square root of two... His wife followed her counterpart, and the attacked priest went the same distance, the other way. Then he said his wife returned home for the night, and the priest knocked at the door. The man, not wanting anything to do with this, ran the only way he could. However, he ran into his wife's counterpart, and now he's stuck here.

Oddly enough, I also remember what I said after that:

> "Well, I guess I came out on top."

I then checked my watch, and the time was 8:00 PM.

#### What was I doing last night? Can you tell me where everyone referenced in the story (me, the Scandinavian man, his wife, his wife's counterpart, and the priest) was?

Comment: I get the vague feeling that zngurzngvpf is involved, and this comes out to be some form of sbezhyn.

Comment: @Dorrulf maybe, maybe not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Going off Kanoo's answer:

> if it's a Scandinavian Defense, the first moves are 1. e4 d5 2. exd5 Qxd5. For a "priest" (bishop) to attack the Qd5, only 3. Bc4 is possible, followed by Qe4+ which checks and attacks the white King. The White Queen blocks with 4. Qe2 and ...Qxc2 attacks both white Bishops.

Now, going from there...

> it's probably 5. Qf3 Qd3 6. Bb3 (going the opposite direction the Queens went) Qd8 (going home) leading to the finish 7. Bxf7+ (knocking on Black's door) Kd7 (forced!) 8. Qd5# mate.

So, in short:

> 1. e4 d5 2. exd5 Qxd5 3. Bc4 Qe4+ 4. Qe2 Qxc2 5. Qf3 Qd3 6. Bb3 Qd8 7. Bxf7+ Kd7 8. Qd5#

I wouldn't be surprising if the time was

> intentionally relating to the number of moves.

Comment: Mmm-hmm. That's it.

Comment: Also, your last assumption is correct

Comment: Well looks like I didn't need to spend more time on it! Good job!

Answer (score 17):

I believe that you were

> Playing Chess

Explanation:

> The [Scandinavian Defense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scandinavian_Defense) is an early chess move. The opponent's bishop (priest) threatened the Queen (wife). The Queen threatened the opponent King (master) and her counterpart (opponent Queen) protected said King. The Queen then threatened both bishops and captured a piece in the process (bumped into) (probably a pawn). The square root of 2 is a reference to 1 diagonal unit's distance, which the opponent Queen and the Scandinavian's Queen moved, thereby threatening a bishop who also moved in the same way. The Queen came back to the Scandinavian's side of the board and an opponent bishop followed. The Scandinavian King retreated, the opponent Queen threatened him and he was checkmated.
> Finally, I believe that you were either the opponent or someone betting against the side that I have been referring to as 'Scandinavian'. Either way, you would win something (game or money).

If by where everyone reference in the story was you want me to show where

> on the board

I'll need to spend a bit more time on it but I will get to it.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean by where everyone referenced in the story was. :P